# Read and manipulate AIML

Tags: c#, xml, artificial-intelligence, aiml

I have an AIML file that I need to interact with using C#.
How do I load the document and use C# to query the file from the user input?

```
<category>
  <pattern>WHAT IS YOUR NAME</pattern>
  <template>My name is John.</template>
</category>
```

The user input would be the pattern. I need to be able to query the file with the user input and return the corresponding template.

Answer (score 1):

Since AIML is an XML dialect, you can use `System.Xml.Linq` types to parse and query it:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(aiml);
// do your queries
XElement category = doc.Descendants("category").Where(cat => cat.Element("pattern").Value == "WHAT IS YOUR NAME").Single();
string template = category.Element("template").Value;
// ...
```